# Не работает сортировка C++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, структуры

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl Sort(void)" (?Sort@@YAHXZ) в функции _main. 6   C:\Users\riteps1\Desktop\6\6\6.obj  1

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1  6   C:\Users\riteps1\Desktop\6\Debug\6.exe  1

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E0254   использование имени типа не допускается 6   C:\Users\riteps1\Desktop\6\6\6.cpp  87

```
// 6.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". Здесь начинается и заканчивается выполнение программы.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>
#include <locale>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996);
using namespace std;
#define SIZELST 100
#define FNAME "Text.txt"
#define COL 80
#define ROW 20

typedef struct
{
    char Naz[35];
    char DataProved[11];
    char VremyProved[11];
    char AdresProved[35];


    char NomLot;
    char FioPr[35];
    char Pas1[35];
    char AdresProdavca[35];
    int NomerTePr;

    double StarCena;
    double FactCena;
    char Opisanie[255];

    char FioPo[35];
    char Pas2[35];
    char AdresPokupately[35];
    int NomerTePo;


}

TAukcion;
TAukcion stud[SIZELST];//массив структур
int nst = 0; //число введенных структур
             //прототипы пользовательских функций
int menu(); // главное меню 
int spisok(); // ввод исходных данных
int resc(); //вывод содержимого текстового файла на экран
int poisk();//поиск по критериям
int delet();// Удаление всех данных из 
int Sort();

void Sort(TAukcion** q, const int n)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1;j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(q[j]->DataProved, q[j + 1]->DataProved) > 0)
            {
                TAukcion* temp = q[j];
                q[j] = q[j + 1];
                q[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    while (true)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1: {spisok(); break; }
        case 2: {resc(); break; }
        case 3: {poisk(); break; }
        case 4: {delet(); break; }
        case 5: {Sort(TAukcion, nst); break; }
        case 0: {return 0; break; }
        default: { cout << "\nВыберите правильно!\n"; }
        }

        cout << "\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения";
        _getch();
        system("cls");
    }
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int menu() //МЕНЮ
{
    system("color 71");
    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
    cout << "                                                                                                                        ";
    cout << "                                              Информационная система - Аукционы                                        \n";
    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "\n ВЫБЕРИТЕ ОПЕРАЦИЮ:" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << " 1 - Добавить информацию  " << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Просмотр всей информации" << endl;
    cout << " 3 - Поиск информации по заданному критерию" << endl;
    cout << " 4 - Удаление данных из текстового файла" << endl;
    cout << " 0 - Выход " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int spisok() // Добавление информации в файл
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251); //нужна библиотека Windows.h
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    system("color 71");
    ofstream outFil(FNAME); // открытие файла для записи и проверка на открытие
    if (!outFil)
    {
        cout << "Не открыт файл" << FNAME;
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n=============================================== ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ В ФАЙЛ ===============================================\n\n\n";
    cout << " Введите число Аукционов: " << endl;
    cin >> nst;
    for (int j = 0; j < nst; j++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Введите название аукциона   \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].Naz, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Введите место проведения : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].AdresProved, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Введите дату проведения : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].DataProved, 11);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Введите время проведения :  \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].VremyProved, 11);
        cin.ignore();


        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Номер лота   \n ";
        cin >> stud[j].NomLot;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " ФИО продовца : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].FioPr, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Номер и серия паспорта через пробел : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].Pas1, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Адрес :  \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].AdresProdavca, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Номер телефон   \n ";
        cin >> stud[j].NomerTePr;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Стартовая цена : \n ";
        cin >> stud[j].StarCena;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Фактическая цена : \n ";
        cin >> stud[j].FactCena;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Описание лота :  \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].Opisanie, 255);
        cin.ignore();


        cin.ignore();
        cout << " ФИО покупателя : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].FioPo, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Номер и серия паспорта через пробел : \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].Pas2, 35);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Адрес :  \n ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].AdresPokupately, 35);;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Номер телефон   \n ";
        cin >> stud[j].NomerTePo;
        cin.ignore();
        outFil << stud[j].Naz << " "
            << stud[j].DataProved << " "
            << stud[j].VremyProved << " "
            << stud[j].AdresProved << " "
            << stud[j].NomLot << " "
            << stud[j].FioPr << " "
            << stud[j].Pas1 << " "
            << stud[j].AdresProdavca << " "
            << stud[j].NomerTePr << " "
            << stud[j].StarCena << " "
            << stud[j].FactCena << " "
            << stud[j].Opisanie << " "
            << stud[j].FioPo << " "
            << stud[j].Pas2 << " "
            << stud[j].AdresPokupately << " "
            << stud[j].NomerTePo << " \n";

    }
    outFil.close();

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int resc()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string textline;
    char matr[ROW][COL];
    int count = -1;

    // Имя открываемого файла, задано в директиве #define
    ifstream inFile(FNAME);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Не открыт файл" << FNAME;
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\nСодержимое файла с данными\n";
    while (getline(inFile, textline))
    {

        count++;
        strcpy(matr[count], textline.c_str());
        cout << "\n" << matr[count];
        cout << "" << endl;

    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int poisk()      // === ПОИСК ДАННЫЕ ИЗ ТЕКСТОВОГО ФАЙЛА ПО КРИТИЮ ===
{
    system("color 71");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    string textline;
    string needle;
    bool founded = false;

    // ВЫВОД СОДЕРЖИМОГО ФАЙЛА НА ЭКРАН ПО КРИТЕРИЮ & ЧТЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА В МАТРИЦУ

    system("cls");
    ifstream inFile(FNAME);
    cout << "\n======================================================== ПОИСК =========================================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "                                 ---------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                                 | Здесь осуществляется поиск Аукциона по критериям.     |\n";
    cout << "                                 | Для этого необходимо вписать критерий и нажать Enter. |\n";
    cout << "                                 ---------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
    cout << "Введите критерий: \n" << endl;
    cin >> needle;
    cout << "\n";

    while (getline(inFile, textline))
    {
        if (textline.find(needle) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << textline << "\n" << endl;
            founded = true;
        }
    }

    if (!founded)
    {
        cout << "Данных по критерию не найдено!" << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int delet()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    system("color 71");
    system("cls");
    ofstream inFile(FNAME, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    cout << "\n================================================= УДАЛЕНИЕ ИНФОРМАЦИИ ==================================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "                       -------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                       | ДАННЫЕ БЫЛИ УСПЕШНО УДАЛЕНЫ |\n";
    cout << "                       -------------------------------\n\n\n";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: @Harry, ну не дубликат это, если по честному. Тут проблема поглубже

Comment: Не сортируется, на выводе нет отсортированой информации.

Comment: функция просмотра печатает содержимое файла. Ей побоку на других. Поэтому, если открыть существующий файл, отсортировать и снова показать файл, то естественно, ничего не поменяется. Нужно сделать нормальную загрузку файла в память. Как то так.

Comment: я полтора часа назад сделал так и всё заработало, спасибо что ответил на комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я всё сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Когда в далекие далекие времена в одной далекой галактике в языке древних си, этот код наверно как то мог работать. Но сейчас, нужно писать сигнатуру функции полностью при ее предварительной объявлении (forward declaration). А у Вас разные

```
int Sort();

void Sort(TAukcion** q, const int n) {..}
```

При чем, сильно разные.

И при вызове передавайте правильно - у Вас ведь указатель на указатель, а передаете **тип**

```
case 5: {Sort(TAukcion, nst); break; }
```

Исправляем где то так

сигнатуру на такую

```
void Sort(TAukcion* q, const int n)
```

и вызов где то так

```
case 5: {Sort(stud, nst); break; }
```

ну и в самой функции сортировки поправить пару стрелок на точки.

Но потом я посмотрел вокруг и понял, что книги по си  не нужно читать, что бы писать на плюсах. К примеру,  не нужно использовать вот такую конструкцию

```
typedef struct {....} TAukcion;
```

можно просто

```
struct TAukcion {....};
```

Вывод - учите нормальный с++, а не вот такую дикую смесь древного си и непонятно чего.

Comment: Спасибо, всё исправил вроде, но сортировка не заработала.